# design by dependency or association

Tags: dependencies, associations

I have a headache with the issue of how to approach a design in terms of dependency or association.
Here is the problem: I need some data to be generated whenever I want. The generation of data is possible only by the knowledge of some other data in hand. So, if I have a class XDataGenerator; it seems to be like this:

```
class XDataGenerator 
{
    void generate ( YData* y_in, ZData* z_in, XData* x_out);
}
```

, where YData and ZData are in "dependency" relation with XDataGenerator class.

However, it is another option to use "association" as the following:

```
class XDataGenerator
{
     YData* mY;
     ZData* mZ;
     void generate( XData* x_out);
}
```

, where YData and ZData are in "association" relation with XDataGenerator class.

In the "dependency" version, x_in and y_in arguments are passed to the function "generate",
In the "association" version, those arguments are accessed via member attributes ( pointers to the objects).

So, what would be the correct approach to this design problem ? How would you approach and why ?
Please note that, y data and z data instances ( used by the XDataGenerator) are subject to change by other entities in the overall design.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the `YData` and `ZData` instances are used by several `XDataGenerator` methods, then define them as instance fields.

If they are subject to change by other entities and you want those changes visible in your `XDataGenerator` instance, then that's fine. If you do not want to see those side effects in your `XDataGenerator` instance, then make defensive copying in the constructors/setters.

If you only need `YData` and `ZData` in the method `generate` and don't want modifications later-on from the outside to effect your `XDataGenerator` instance, then do not use instance fields but only the parameters inside `generate`.

And now to a general remark about dependencies: To avoid the dependency on implementations, I would rather program against interfaces, i.e. use an interface or abstract class for the parameters of the constructor / setter as well as the instance field definition. Then at runtime, you can swap between different implementations of that interface. Or use the same implementation with some modifications that are not visible through the interface.

---

Update:

Your title is slightly confusing, since association implies dependencies. To read some more about the terminology, here's a corresponding [blog post by Uncle Bob](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DependencyAndAssociation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I want those changes visible by the generate method.

Comment: Actually, YData and ZData are updated continously and ZData should be updated accordingly to be synchronized with those changes. 

There is a single instance of XDataGenerator which wants to see the latest states of those YData and ZData instances.

So, it seems that it is equally correctto use any of them ( dependency or association ), right ?

I did not understand how to apply your suggestion of using interfaces, here

Comment: Yes, both instance fields and parameters will do. I would save the YData and ZData objects in XDataGenerator as instance fields without defensive copying, and use a getter (for instance named generate) to get the corresponding current XData.

Comment: Actually, the following design, if applicable, would be the nicest for my taste: Use a class Koordinate and within that public static Koordinate getX(Koordinate y, Koordinate z) (in Java notation, but applies equally for C++).